# Retrieving Non Null Values Query, returns the previous previous value instead

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I've written the following query, which for OccupancyID 182 returns the correct values. However for OccupancyID 3313 with a date of 2024-03-01, it returns 150015 rather than 100812.

The query is trying to meet the need of returning the most recent CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID across the date periods. For OccupancyID 3313, the FeedbackID 150015 was valid for 2023-11-01 and 2023-12-01, but then 100812 came in and is the ID that should be used carrying forward from theen onward until it changes again.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Expected Results

| OccupancyID | FirstDayOfMonth | CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID | PreviousNonNULLCustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 182 | 2023-10-01 | NULL | NULL |
| 182 | 2023-11-01 | 100571 | NULL |
| 182 | 2023-12-01 | NULL | 100571 |
| 182 | 2024-01-01 | NULL | 100571 |
| 182 | 2024-02-01 | NULL | 100571 |
| 182 | 2024-03-01 | NULL | 100571 |
| 3313 | 2023-10-01 | NULL | NULL |
| 3313 | 2023-11-01 | 150015 | NULL |
| 3313 | 2023-12-01 | NULL | 150015 |
| 3313 | 2024-01-01 | 100812 | 150015 |
| 3313 | 2024-02-01 | NULL | 100812 |
| 3313 | 2024-03-01 | NULL | 100812 (this shows as 150015 currently which is wrong) |

```
drop table if exists #temp2

CREATE TABLE #temp2
(
    [FirstDayOfMonth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [OccupancyID] [int] NULL,
    [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID] [int] NULL,
    [RowNumber] [bigint] NULL
)
GO
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2023-10-01' AS Date), 3313, NULL, 1)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2023-11-01' AS Date), 3313, 150015, 2)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2023-12-01' AS Date), 3313, NULL, 3)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2024-01-01' AS Date), 3313, 100812, 4)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2024-02-01' AS Date), 3313, NULL, 5)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2024-03-01' AS Date), 3313, NULL, 6)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2023-10-01' AS Date), 182, NULL, 1)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2023-11-01' AS Date), 182, 100571, 2)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2023-12-01' AS Date), 182, NULL, 3)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2024-01-01' AS Date), 182, NULL, 4)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2024-02-01' AS Date), 182, NULL, 5)
INSERT #temp2 ([FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID], [RowNumber]) VALUES (CAST(N'2024-03-01' AS Date), 182, NULL, 6)
GO

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        FirstDayOfMonth, 
        OccupancyID, 
        CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID,
        RowNumber,
        LAG(CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID) OVER(PARTITION BY OccupancyID ORDER BY FirstDayOfMonth) AS Lag_Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OccupancyID ORDER BY FirstDayOfMonth) AS RN,
        CASE WHEN CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Flag            
    FROM 
        #temp2
)
SELECT 
    OccupancyID, 
    FirstDayOfMonth, 
    CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID,
    CASE 
        WHEN Lag_Value IS NULL THEN PreviousCustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID
        ELSE Lag_Value 
    END AS PreviousNonNULLCustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,
    (
        SELECT 
            TOP(1) CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID 
        FROM 
            CTE c
        WHERE 
            c.Flag = 1 AND 
            c.RN < a.RN AND 
            c.OccupancyID = a.OccupancyID
    ) AS PreviousCustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID
    FROM CTE 
a) a
```

Comment: `SELECT  TOP(1)` without `ORDER BY` returns an arbitrary row.

Comment: @Serg, yeah I thought that was the case, any suggestions on getting around that?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind what you are trying to do. "returns the correct values" why are they correct and the others not, please explain the steps.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, have edited. Hope that helps explain it?

Comment: `OccupancyID = a.OccupancyID` syntax like this is a *terrible* idea and leads to behaviour which is [*not a bug* in SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20220523085107/https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2019/04/23/no-this-is-not-a-bug-in-t-sql/). Always qualify your column names.

Comment: @ThomA, yes quite right. It was oversight.

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2022 or Azure SQL you can just use `IGNORE NULLS` in the `LAG`

Comment: @Charlieface - yes I would have loved to use that but unfortunately stuck on SQL 2017

Comment: @Charlieface - it will always be increasing. It's an Identity field.

Comment: @NishantGupta - will do

Comment: But `150015` is higher than `100812` so clearly that's not always true. Anywa not sure why so complicated, you don't even need the row number https://dbfiddle.uk/UzZKJkez

Comment: @Philip is ROWNUMBER column already given in the base table?

Comment: @NishantGupta - yes

Comment: @Charlieface - ahh! You are quite right! Sorry! Thanks for the dbfiddle!

Comment: @Philip i updated my solution and provided a new query. Kindly check and let me know if it is working for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

Using a kind of gaps and islands request

```
select [FirstDayOfMonth], [OccupancyID], [CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID],
     max(prev) over(partition by [OccupancyID], grp) [PreviousNonNULLCustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID]
  from (
   select *, sum(d) over(partition by [OccupancyID] order by [FirstDayOfMonth] rows unbounded preceding) grp
   from (
      select *,
         case when lag([CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID]) over(partition by [OccupancyID] order by [FirstDayOfMonth]) is null then 0 else 1 end d,
         lag([CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID]) over(partition by [OccupancyID] order by [FirstDayOfMonth]) prev
      from #temp2
   ) t
) t
order by [OccupancyID], [FirstDayOfMonth]
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ywXOkJWS)

Comment: `rows unbounded preceding` in the `sum` is more efficient, and in some cases more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.OccupancyID, 
    t.FirstDayOfMonth, 
    t.CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY 
                      t.OccupancyID, 
                      t.FirstDayOfMonth, 
                      t.CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID 
         ORDER BY c.ROWNUMBER DESC) 
    AS PreviousNonNULLCustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID
FROM #temp2 as t
LEFT JOIN #temp2 c
ON t.OccupancyID = c.OccupancyID
AND t.FirstDayOfMonth > c.FirstDayOfMonth
AND c.CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.OccupancyID, 
    t.FirstDayOfMonth
```

Link to DbFiddle: [Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nXSEevwx)

Solution after changing a little bit of your solution:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        FirstDayOfMonth, 
        OccupancyID, 
        CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID,
        RowNumber,
        LAG(CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID) OVER(PARTITION BY OccupancyID ORDER BY FirstDayOfMonth) AS Lag_Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OccupancyID ORDER BY FirstDayOfMonth) AS RN,
        CASE WHEN CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Flag            
    FROM 
        #temp2
)
SELECT 
    OccupancyID, 
    FirstDayOfMonth, 
    CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID,
    CASE 
        WHEN Lag_Value IS NULL THEN PreviousCustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID
        ELSE Lag_Value 
    END AS PreviousNonNULLCustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,
    (
        SELECT 
            TOP(1) CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID 
        FROM 
            CTE c
        WHERE 
            c.Flag = 1 AND 
            c.RN < a.RN AND 
            c.OccupancyID = a.OccupancyID
        ORDER BY RN DESC
    ) AS PreviousCustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID
    FROM CTE 
a) a
```

I just added **ORDER BY RN DESC** in correlated subquery to take that value of "**CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID**" which is having highest RN value(in case there are more than 1 value of "CustomerVoice_RepairsSatisfactionFeedbackID" in correlated subquery).

For example, for "OccupancyID" - 3313 and "FirstDayOfMonth" - 2024-03-01, the correlated subquery is giving more than 1 value(i.e.150015 and 100812) and you are taking the TOP(1) value which is giving value as 150015.

For Same value of "OccupancyID" - 3313 and "FirstDayOfMonth" - 2024-03-01, the query is checking whether lag is null or not and in this case it is not null and hence it has taken 100812 as the value and not from the correlated subquery.